# Calling a parametriesd constructor without the parametr will throw error?

Tags: php, oop

I have this class like this  in php

```
class database 

 var $db;
{

       function ___constructor($db)
            {
                $this->db= $db;

               }



}
```

Now I am calling it like this

```
$obj = new database();
```

Its throwing error How can I fix this ?

Isint it suppose to call the default constructor automatically . When I am not passing any value.

Comment: `___constructor` that should contain only two underscores and it really should be `__construct`. There is no "constructor" in OOP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens, because you add the `$db` befor you open the class with `{`.

Use like this:

```
class database {
    var $db; //Comes here
    function __construct($db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

And please, see the comments, below this answer.

Comment: `___constructor` still contains too many underscores, plus there is no "constructor" in OOP, it's "construct" ;) `__construct` => http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

Comment: @lolka_bolka sorry for the wrong syntax . I check in my file the class I have written is right also the method is called  __construct($db)  what I think is wrong here is that I need to provide default value to the constructor . As mentioned by the DAN .

Answer (score 2):

Your current constructor requires a parameter to be passed. You need to supply a default value for the parameter in the method definition.

```
   function __construct($db='default') {
        $this->db = $db;
    }
```

Also your brackets are wrong. `var $db` is not in the class definition. Which I'm pretty sure won't parse right. Move the opening bracket to right after the class name

```
class database{
...
}
```

And it looks like you have too many underscores in the constructor name it should have 2 `__construct`